# Ошибка при передачи данных из Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Мне необходимо отобразить из БД в раскрывающий список ФИО, у которых столбец *SubjectCode равен 1*.

**Ege15VM.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Ege15VM
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Participants { get; set; }
        public string Participant { get; set; }

        public Ege15VM()
        {
            cokoEntitiesWAN dataContext = new cokoEntitiesWAN();
            Participants = from a in dataContext.ege_15_res_before
                           where a.SubjectCode == 1
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                              Text = a.surname + " " + a.name,
                              Value = a.ParticipantID,
                              Selected = false
                           };
        }
    }
}
```

**Ege15.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Ege15VM

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {        
            Фамилия, Имя участника: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Participant, Model.Participants)

        <p><input type="submit" value="Сформировать отчет" /></p>

    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Ege15()
{
    var model = new Ege15VM();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ege15(Ege15VM model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Представление нормально отображается и раскрывающий список содержит необходимые ФИО. Но если нажать на "Сформировать отчет", т.е. вызвать POST, выскакивает ошибка:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Сообщение ссылается на строку

```
Фамилия, Имя участника: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Participant, Model.Participants)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эта строчка:

```
return View();
```

возвращает View, который будет отрендерен на основе ModelData - данных, переданных от клиента. model при этом будет null.

замените ее на

```
return View(model);
```